# How to determine if a web page is jquery-enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to determine if a webpage is jquery enabled? Using jquery itself if that's the best way to determine it.

Comment: you want to check if the page already has jquery library included?

Comment: What is "jQuery-enabled" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if(jQuery) //jquery object exists
```

jQuery isn't magic - it's essentially just a big object.  You can check for it like you would any other object.

Same thing to ensure libraries within jQuery are loaded:

```
if(jQuery.DatePicker) //lib exists
```

Comment: Cheers, havent used javascript or jquery in months so a bit rusty.

Comment: If jQuery isn't enabled, it will throw an error, and halt execution of your script.

Answer (score 16):

The best way to check if jQuery is loaded is

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
}
```

If you check using `if(jQuery){}`, and it isn't there, you are going to get a reference error like below, and **it will break the execution of your script**. By checking if the window object has a property called jQuery, if it isn't there, it will simply return undefined.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... The topanswer only works if jQuery is in fact present.

Answer (score 9):

Run this in the console:

```
if (window.jQuery) { 
    console.log("Yes there's jQuery!"); 
} else { 
    console.log("Nope, it's not on this site..."); 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Check in javascript if the jquery object exists.

Use the below if condition to check if jQuery object exists.

```
if(jQuery)
{
//jquery object exists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do a check to see if the javascript object is initialised.

```
if(jQuery)
{
    alert('jquery active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (jQuery) { // yup it's there }`

Answer (score 0):

Well we have the working answers available.. Though for some lazy people that want even smart answer I would like to add :
Simply try hitting

> $

key word in the console of browser
if (jQuery is loaded) then you would get

> ƒ (e,t){return new E.fn.init(e,t)}

which is the minified jQuery library
else
it would throw reference error

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use `typeof` operator.

```js
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    // jQuery IS loaded
}
```