# How to know if a webpage has jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, selenium

I am working on selenium and wanted to have a method to check if the page has loaded completely or not.

For this, i wrote a method to check jquery and page is fully loaded or not. This method works fine if the page has jquery. But the code is getting stuck if the page do not have a jQuery.

Is there a way to check, prior to run the method, that the page has jquery or not.

[I referred this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631333/how-to-determine-if-a-web-page-is-jquery-enabled), but i could not implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The second answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631333/how-to-determine-if-a-web-page-is-jquery-enabled) you linked to is actually the better one.  The code in the accepted answer will throw a reference error if JQuery is not defined.

My preference would be to use the same test I use to check for any object:

```
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' && jQuery !== null) { ... }
```

Comment: This is probably a good answer but the reference to "second answer" is a bit vague and may not be the second answer there now. Better to quote and link to the answer (can be done :))

Answer (score 0):

simply we can use

if(jQuery){

```
    //jquery object exists
```

}else{

```
   //NO jquery object
```

}